# Communication between Android Client SSL and Netty Socket server SSL

Tags: android, ssl, netty

Any have idea for how to connect with Android Client SSL with Netty Socket SSL Server?

This is server code. ([SecureChatSslContextFactory](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatSslContextFactory.java))

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\StartSSL\\pkcsserver.p12"); //secret");

    // Set up key manager factory to use our key store
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    kmf.init(ks, keyPass);

    // Initialize the SSLContext to work with our key managers.
    serverContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
    serverContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```

This is Android Client Code:

```
        KeyStore ksTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ksTrust.load(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pkcsserver), passphrase);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ksTrust);

        //get context
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        //init context
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
```

Please tell me someone where I am wrong.